# How to cache XML file in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, caching

I am obtaining an XML file from a remote server which contains fairly static data.  Here is my code:

```
$dom = simplexml_load_file("foo.xml");

foreach ($dom->bar->baz as $item) {
echo $item;
}
```

Since the data is rarely changing, there is no need to ping the server on each page load...How can I cache foo.xml in a simple manner?  Keep in mind that I am a beginner...

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A very simplistic cache would be to store the xml file into a directory, and updated every hour or so

```
$cacheName = 'somefile.xml.cache';
// generate the cache version if it doesn't exist or it's too old!
$ageInSeconds = 3600; // one hour
if(!file_exists($cacheName) || filemtime($cacheName) > time() + $ageInSeconds) {
  $contents = file_get_contents('http://www.something.com/foo.xml');
  file_put_contents($cacheName, $contents);
}

$dom = simplexml_load_file($cacheName);
// ...
```

note: This of course assumes several things like the file was successfully generated, the remote file successfully downloaded, etc.

Comment: what happen if the page is access by two different users with different computers? and with diffrent parameters?

Comment: Don't forget `clearstatcache()` with the `filemtime()` function.

Comment: Why not `time() - filemtime($cacheName) >= $ageInSeconds`?

Comment: Just a comment, many years later -- as stated in the answer, the cache will never trigger, because the time comparison is backwards.  You need to use the time comparison in the comment just above.