# ajax post request is No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, cross-domain-policy

I'm just making an ajax post request and I'm getting an error like:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://xxx.com?redirect_uri=http://www.example.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

And here I can see there is nothing different from my response domain and request domain except "www", so does "www" also cause this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery xml error ' No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821753/jquery-xml-error-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-req)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because you are making a cross-domain AJAX request, which prevented by browser security - see the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

The request is expecting you to be making a request to a CORS enabled domain, hence why it is complaining about the non-existant header.

You either need to change your request to `jsonp` type, or use a server-side proxy to get the data.

Comment: is www also an issue here?

Comment: No, not at all, assuming the non-www version of the domain is forwarded on correctly in the DNS.

Comment: actually my response is expecting www and my request domain is not having it. But both the domains are same only difference is with and without "www". My doubt is only on this.

Comment: In that case use a relative path. If both domains are exactly the same (down to the port and protocol) then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

When requesting data from external website it is always best to not do it in ajax , but if you have to do it an ajax have a internal page which makes a call with server side code and call that page with ajax.