# javascript code is not working in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, json, http

Here is my code it will send get request and renders some content of the response in html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Mytitle</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function httpGet() {
            var xmlHttp = null;
            var x = document.getElementById("city").value;
            var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=chennai&units=metric&mode=json";
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
            xmlHttp.send();
            var obj1 = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText.toString());
            document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = obj1.message
                    + " " + obj1.list[0].name;

        }
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="city" />
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="httpGet()" />
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

this code is working perfectly when i run in eclipse browser. but its failing  in Browser.
I have checked browser configuration for script enabling and its enabled. and also no issue with browser configuration.

Im new to javascript http requests.
Please suggest

Comment: Yeah, that's not a very modern way to make an AJAX call. Can you use jQuery?

Comment: Related Question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821753/jquery-xml-error-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-req

Comment: And why don't you debug javascript in your browser.? There are many plugins available for debuging. Like Firebug in firefox and Chrome has inbuilt debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read somewhere that the Eclipse browser doesn't adhere to the [**same origin policy** *<sup>[Wikipedia]</sup>*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). That's why it is possible to make an Ajax request to an external URL, something that is not possible *by default* in a "normal" browser.

And indeed if I try to [run your code *<sup>[jsFiddle]</sup>*](http://jsfiddle.net/t547r/), I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=chennai&units=metric&mode=json`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin `'http://fiddle.jshell.net'` is therefore not allowed access.

There are [multiple ways to work around the same-origin policy *<sup>[SO]</sup>*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy). In your case it seems that the service supports [JSONP *<sup>[SO]</sup>*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2067472/218196).

With JSONP, your not making an Ajax call to the server, but instead you are using the URL with a dynamically created script element. Script elements are not restricted by the same-origin policy and therefore can load data (code) from other servers.

The server will return a JavaScript file which contains a single function call. The name of the function is specified by you via a query parameter. So, if the JSON response is usually:

```
{"message":"accurate","cod":"200", ...}
```

by adding the argument `callback=foo` to the URL, the server returns

```
foo({"message":"accurate","cod":"200", ...});
```

(follow [this URL](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=chennai&units=metric&mode=json&callback=foo) to see an example for your service)

This response can be evaluated as JavaScript. **Note** that you can **not** turn every JSON response into JSONP. JSONP must be supported by the server.

Here is a complete example:

```
// this function must be global since the script is executed in global scope
function processResponse(obj1) {
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = 
        obj1.message + " " + obj1.list[0].name;
}

function httpGet() {
    var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=chennai&units=metric&mode=json";
    // the following line is just to explictly show the `callback` parameter
    url += '&callback=processResponse';
    //                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ name of our function

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/t547r/1/)

If you google for JSONP, you will find [more information *<sup>[Wikipedia]</sup>*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) and tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

I think ur xmlhttprequest instance is not getting created. It is some time browser dependent try this..

```
     var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 { your code  }
```

Comment: While this might be helpful in general, this is not the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to needing a cross browser xmlhttpquest (which for that alone I'd use jQuery), you also need to wait for the document ready before accessing the city by id... that is, move your script block after your city definition (and I think you may need a form, depending on browser).
Perhaps something like this

```
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="city" />
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="httpGet()" />
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function httpGet() {
        if (typeof (document.getElementById("city")) == 'undefined') {
          alert("Maybe console.log our alarm... but the sky appears to be falling.");
        }
        var xmlHttp = null;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            var obj1 = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText.toString());
            document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = obj1.message
                + " " + obj1.list[0].name;
          }
        }
        var x = document.getElementById("city").value;
        var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=chennai&units=metric&mode=json";
        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
        xmlHttp.send();
      }
  </script>
  <div id="placeholder"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Uhm, the code is executed when the button is clicked, at which point the element with ID `#city` already exists. Regarding DOM access the code is perfectly fine.

Comment: On closer inspection I see that you're correct, however it's still good advice.

Comment: i tried moving script block to after city definition ..but still not successfull

Comment: for simplicity i have removed city input tag and get element of city in script code.. so now i will he having only submit button. still im not able to get the response from browser.

Answer (score -1):

```
function httpGet() {
    var xmlHttp = null;
    var x = document.getElementById("city").value;
    var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=chennai&units=metric&mode=json";
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
         var obj1 = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText.toString());
         document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = obj1.message
                    + " " + obj1.list[0].name;
    }
    xmlHttp.send();
 }
```

Comment: Can't you see? I add event listener for waiting a ajax to finish.

Comment: Nope, didn't see it when I glanced over the code. **Always** explain your solution, don't just post code. While your code is not incorrect, the event handler is not necessary. This code performance a *synchronous* request (`xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);`) and that's why it is possible to access the response as done in the original code. Or to say it differently: Your change doesn't change the behavior of the code and hence cannot solve the problem.