# Failed to load resource error in Angular js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

While try to run the following function in angular

```
$scope.login = function (user, LoginForm) {

        $http.get('http://localhost/Angular/index.php/core/login').success(function (data) {
            $scope.message = data;
        });
    };
```

it shows the following error

(Im working with this code in webstorm)

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```
http://localhost/Angular/index.php/api/login:0
```

Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '`http://localhost:63342'` is therefore not allowed access.

```
http://localhost/Angular/index.php/api/login:0
```

XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost/LAngular/index.php/api/login`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin `'http://localhost:63342'` is therefore not allowed access.

How to fix this?

Comment: This answer (jquery related) can help you. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821753/jquery-xml-error-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-req

Even it is jquery it will show you how to deal with Origin Policy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This indicates the Api doesnt support Cross origin requests

so the request should be 'JSONP'

```
$http.jsonp('http://localhost/Angular/index.php/core/login')
```

For more about this issue : http://www.arunisrael.com/2013/08/accessing-external-apis-with-angularjs.html