# Is it possible to get this Json?

Tags: jquery, json

I've been trying to get Json from this page: http://ehv-design.nl/eindopdracht/api.php?method=complete (no json file). Is it even possible to get this? I'v tried to get it with this code:

```
 var url = 'http://ehv-design.nl/eindopdracht/api.php?method=complete';


$.getJSON(url, function(data){
     var name = data[name];
     $("#photoInfo").append("<p>"+name+"</p>"); 
});
```

Comment: Nope, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource, so you can't get that.

Comment: When you have a chance, take a look at my answer. You can do it using YQL. It's simple and prevents you from having to set up a server side proxy of your own to consume the JSON object. I'm only commenting because you're getting a lot of "no" answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The server does not send CORS headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) so no, you cannot retrieve and access the result unless you use a wrapper on your server that retrieves the remote file and makes it available locally.

Another option would be asking the owner of the remote service to support JSONp. Then you could use that to retrieve the data even without CORS headers. But CORS would be much cleaner for sure (JSONP is basically cross site scripting, you just trust the remote end not to execute malicious code).

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely can using YQL (Yahoo Query Language).

```
var query = 'http://ehv-design.nl/eindopdracht/api.php?method=complete'
var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22' + encodeURIComponent(query) + '%22&format=json&callback=?'

$.getJSON(url, function (res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

[I made a fiddle demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/54pz8/)

Comment: I wouldn't want to rely on an external service for this. Why add another possible point of failure?

Comment: While I get your concern, YQL has been around for years and is a tried and true web service owned and maintained by Yahoo. You can't always get JSONp from a service, and some people can't roll their own server side proxy. He also asked if it's possible, which it is, as I've proved.

Comment: This is a really neat approach! +1 for introducing me to YQL.

Answer (score -1):

The server hosting that JSON does not allow [cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). I tried running the code from jsfiddle.net. When trying to access the file the following error is logged:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ehv-design.nl/eindopdracht/api.php?method=complete.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

For further reading, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821851/3071418)