# Phonegap No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, cordova

In phonegap I have an issue while calling a PHP file using jQuery AJAX. The error that occurs while calling the file is:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Google said to put this code `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` in the current PHP file header. I put the code in the header, but still no changes. I've attached my [jsfidde](http://jsfiddle.net/sriram3101/wCVNR/1/) with it.

The file `connectionsqlphp.php` code is here

```
<?php 

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo "hi";

?>
```

Comment: do you have `<access origin="*" />` in your config.xml file?

Comment: @Dawson Loudon yes I have

Comment: are you testing on the phone/simulator or inside your browser? Origin errors are more likely to happen if you are testing on a desktop browser.

Comment: I'm not a php expert, but are you sure `echo "hi"` will generate a valid json output???

Comment: @Ekim I checked in browser in phone its not giving any error just simply blink thats all..

Comment: @QuickFix I just want to display hi via json in my file I don't know how let me know if you have any ideas about this..

Comment: Looks realy Like a CORS problem, there are some great resources and answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821753/jquery-xml-error-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-req

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There should be no cross origin issue in phonegap/cordova as long as you configure properly access origin in config.xml.

It's normal that you have this message when testing from a browser if you miss some CORS headers.Try adding :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
```

But once again you don't need those headers for a phonegap app.

When you do `echo "hi";`, your're not sending json but sending a text "hi". (just writing json in the header does not format what you echo).

I think you should either use `$.get` in the javascript and remove `header('Content-Type: application/json');` from php so that the app expects a simple text or modify your php to really send JSON.

for ex:

```
echo "{message:\"hi\"}";
```