# Not able to send restful server using post method in javascript in PHONEGAP android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

i m using the same code and not able to send restful request in phonegap
getting error Access-control-allow-origin is null.

`//JSON OBJECT

```
var obj = {
        "userId": UserId,
        "userName1": UserName1,
        "userName2": UserName2,
        "recipientType":RecipientType,
        "RecipientValue":RecipientValue,
        }

        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);
            alert(jsonString);

//THIS IS HOW I SEND JSON OBJECT

            var url = "http://someurl";
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.open( "post", url, false );
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            xmlHttp.send(jsonString);
            alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
```

`

Comment: is your "http://someurl" and application on same domain ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phonegap No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21773303/phonegap-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-res)

Comment: yes and i hv also tried

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<phonegap>
    <access origin="*" />
    <log level="DEBUG"/>
</phonegap>

Comment: in PHONEGAP.xml file

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. at null:1