# ajax error on simple query?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Why does the following throw an error?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: str,
    crossDomain: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error.statusText);
    },
});
```

The value of the variable `str` is `"http://deepview.info/getTableData.php?uid=5405&exchange=NASDAQ&symbol=MSFT&startDate=1391212800&endDate=1393632000"`

What I really need is to save the output to a json file...

Comment: what error does it throw ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: it just says "error"

Comment: It also says _o 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource._

Comment: @putvande -- that seems a bit beyond me...

Comment: I think it meens so much as that you are not allowed to access it.

Comment: @putvande: ?? That doesn't seem to make sense since if I just paste that string into my browser, I get all the information!

Comment: Yes. But not if you request it via an xmlhttprequest. It is a security thing.

Comment: @putvande: ok, so how would I need to change it?

Comment: It looks like you can't.

Comment: @putvande: even if I do dataType:jsonp, as suggested it still doesn't work...

Comment: you can try http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery xml error ' No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821753/jquery-xml-error-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-req)

Comment: @Quentin, you must be prescient as this eventually led me to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
str = "http: //deepview.info/getTableData.php";
formData = {
    uid: "5405",
    exchange: "NASDAQ",
    symbol: "MSFT",
    startDate: "1391212800",
    endDate: "1393632000"
}
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: str,
    crossDomain: true,
    data: formData,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
});
```

Comment: Try also to add `dataType: "jsonp"`

Comment: try again once more. my mistake

Comment: figured it out, nothing to do with this. had to do with jsonp structure.