# Manuplation a dynamic page's output using html, javascript or client based technologies

Tags: javascript, php, html, asp.net, dom

There is a plan like this;

- Create an html page.
- Create a button on the html page.
- Create a function for the button's click event that does a call to a
     dynamic page such as ; http://xyzexampleserver.com/QR/query/gettable.asp which
     presents an html table while it is called directly.
- Get the table from the called page.
- Show it on the html page (created on the 1 item)

The question is here using another page's result value on an html page using javascript or any client based technologies.

How can I call the gettable.asp  and use the return value (the html source code), in the buttons click event?

Comment: SO is not a todo list :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using an AJAX call on your dynamic page, getting the HTML response and putting it in your HTML page. This would be quite easy using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: I tried but there says that I can not call cross domain. How can I get over it ?= )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821753/jquery-xml-error-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-req