# html file not call from other server , with jquery .load()

Tags: jquery

I have a code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.Designer').load('http://www.barsamservice.com/1.txt');

});
```

but , the text file not loaded .

but if i download text file and upload it in my server . 
Text file is loaded

***How do I use Access-Control-Allow-Origin***

Comment: where is your file first of all?? where you are storing it??

Comment: load() function is limited to the current domain.

Comment: You have to enabel Cross. this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821753/jquery-xml-error-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-req

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Which file ?

Comment: `http://www.barsamservice.com/1.txt`.. The one you are trying to load!! Is it in same server or different server??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao different server , but is mine

Comment: Then you need to learn more on what @ImreNagy has mentioned in his answer!! You have allow request to your server from `Cross Domain`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).
You can only get the information if the other server has a running service that is reading the text file and gives you the output on request.