# Classic ASP Parse JSON Error with ASPJSON.com Library

Tags: json, parsing, asp-classic

I'm trying to use GET to parse JSON from a URL with Classic ASP. There seems to be a cross-domain issue. I use the library from http://www.aspjson.com/ and get a '80072efd' msxml3.dll error. Which reads as: "A connection with the server could not be established". This is happening at aj_XmlHttp.send.

```
Set aj_XmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
aj_XmlHttp.open "GET", inputsource, False
aj_XmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/json"
aj_XmlHttp.setRequestHeader "CharSet", "UTF-8"
aj_XmlHttp.Send
```

I previously tried jsonp to parse the JSON but got an XMLHttpRequest error where nothing would load load due to an Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue.

Here's my code:

```
Set oJSON = New aspJSON
oJSON.loadJSON("https://api.rtsports.com/daily/xxxxxxx/baseball/period")

Response.Write oJSON.data("sport") & "<br>"

For Each phonenr In oJSON.data("period")
   Set this = oJSON.data("period").item(phonenr)
   Response.Write _
    this.item("start_time") & ": " & _
    this.item("end_time") & "<br>"
Next

Response.Write oJSON.JSONoutput()
```

JSON

```
"sport": "baseball",
"period": [{
   "period_id": "1770",
   "sport": "baseball",
   "start_time": "Thu May 7 1:10 PM ET",
   "end_time": "Fri May 8 12:00 AM ET",
   "games": [{
     "home_team": "MIN",
     "away_team": "OAK",
     "start_time": "Thu May 7 1:10 PM ET"
   }]
}]
```

Does anyone know of a way to parse cross-domain JSON using Classic ASP and avoid the connection or Access-Control-Allowed-Origin error? I don't have access to server settings.

**Resolved**

The problem was that the JSON I was accessing did not have a certificate matching the URL. Instead of accessing it through https I switched to http and had no trouble.

Comment: Since you don't have access to open up server access to external domains, you may try some of the tips in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821753/jquery-xml-error-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-req

Comment: Please add solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the JSON I was accessing did not have a certificate matching the URL. Instead of accessing it through https I switched to http and had no trouble.