# JQuery not working with Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

```
$(document).ready(function(){       // load jQuery 1.5
  function loadfail(){
  alert("Error: Failed to read file!");
 }

 function parse(document){
 $(document).find("el").each(function(){
    var optionLabel = $(this).find('text').text();
    var optionValue = $(this).find('value').text();
    $('#el').append(
   '<option value="'+ optionValue + '">' + optionLabel + '</option>'
    );
 });
 }

 $.ajax({
  url: "ednlevel.xml",    // name of file with our data - link has been renamed
  dataType: 'xml',    // type of file we will be reading
  success: parse,     // name of function to call when done reading file
  error: loadfail     // name of function to call when failed to read
 });
});
```

The above code works fine with Firefox but it isn't working on chrome or Internet Explorer. What is wrong with it?

Comment: i am getting an error as "Unable to read file"

Comment: Press F12 to get your error log and check it

Comment: It would help you told us what is not working. What do you see and what do you expect to see.

Answer (score 0):

By default, on local, chrome and IE not working with ajax request. (same origin error).

Please try to put your file directly on server. Or active adequate header (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) on your local server.

And add content-type and send request parameter:

```
$.ajax({
        type:"get",
        url: "ednlevel.xml",    // name of file with our data - link has been renamed
        dataType: 'xml',    // type of file we will be reading
        contentType: "text/xml",
        success: parse,     // name of function to call when done reading file
        error: loadfail     // name of function to call when failed to read
    });
```

You can can find more information here : [jQuery xml error ' No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821753/jquery-xml-error-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-req)