# Is the format of this Vue resource header wrong?

Tags: vue.js, http-headers, vue-resource

This is the API specs:

```
POST /user/v1/profile:
headers: istaging-token: USER_TOKEN
body:{
  buildingLimit: 10
}
```

And this is how I'm doing it in the code:

```
api.updateUser = (formData, sessionToken) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const URLEnd = '/users/profile'
    const options = api.apiTimeout
    options.headers = { 'istaging-token': sessionToken }
    Vue.http.post(api.serverURL + api.apiVersion + URLEnd, formData, options).then(resp => {
      if (resp.status === 200) resolve(resp)
      else reject(resp)
    }, err => {
      console.log('update user error: ', err)
      reject(err)
    })
  })
}
```

But I get this error:

> Failed to load https://vrbackend.leanapp.cn/api/v1/users/profile:
>   Request header field istaging-token is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Is there something  wrong with the formatting of my headers? Or this is a server issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something wrong with the formatting of my headers? Or this is a server issue?

It is a server issue.

Check the network tab of the developer tools. The preflight `OPTIONS` request didn't find `istaging-token` in the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`, thus it is denying access to it.

Solution: the server must return the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` containing `istaging-token`.

Details:

- More on the [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15444439/1850609) and how it works.
- More on [CORS and the preflight request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821851/1850609).