# API call over AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, get

I'm new to AJAX and I want to generate a password over [this](https://passwordwolf.com/?length=10&upper=off&lower=off&special=off&exclude=012345&repeat=5) API. I want to use AJAX but dont know exactly how and where to specify the parameters.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://passwordwolf.com/?length=10&upper=off&lower=off&special=off&exclude=012345&repeat=5',
    dataType: "text json",
    type: "POST",
    data: {upper: off, lower: on, special: off},
    success: function(jsonObject,status) {

        console.log("function() ajaxPost : " + status);

    }
});
```

Many Thanks, Pls don't hate my programming skills!

Comment: it depends on whether the API you're calling expects the variables to be sent on the querystring (i.e. part of the URL) or in the request body (i.e. included via the `data` option). You need to check that first and then you'll know what to do.

Comment: @ADyson From looking at the URL I can tell it must be in the URL can I then leave out the data: part completely?

Comment: Yes. Also check which HTTP method the API requires you to use (i.e. GET or POST or PUT or DELETE). If you're using ajax cross-domain you also need to verify whether it supports CORS or not - if not then an ajax request won't work.

Comment: Also, having visited the URL above, which is a HTML page designed for users to view, it suggests a different API link in order to get the data in machine-readable JSON format - `https://passwordwolf.com/api/?upper=off&lower=off&special=off&length=10&exclude=012345&repeat=5` is the correct URL to call the actual API. And it should be done via a GET (since I was able to paste the URL into the browser bar and run it from there, which always causes a GET)

Comment: However, as demoed here: https://jsfiddle.net/5a2xayy2/ the API doesn't support CORS (see the error in your browser's console). So you'll have to make your request from a non-ajax context, or use the workaround shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a look at their API:

- You should use the `GET` method, not `POST`.
- The url should be `https://passwordwolf.com/api/` (notice the `/api` at the end).
- Besides, passwordwolf doesn't accept CORS, so you should probably call that service from your server side and mirror it to your frontend with the [appropriate CORS headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821851/1850609).

See demo below (it uses cors-anywhere to circunvent the CORS problem).

It also shows how to correctly **use an object to set params**.

```js
var CORS = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';

$.ajax({
  url: CORS + 'https://passwordwolf.com/api/',
  dataType: "json",
  type: "GET",
  data: {
    length: 10,
    upper: "off",
    lower: "off",
    special: "off",
    exclude: "012345",
    repeat: 5
  },
  success: function(jsonObject, status) {
    console.log("ajax result: " + JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```